# How to Send / Receive AudioKit MIDI Messages Directly Between iOS Device and Keyboard?

Tags: ios, macos, midi, audiokit, coremidi

I'm developing an audio-visual iOS app and using [AudioKit](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit) for MIDI communication between the app and MIDI controllers. When running the iOS Simulator and when connecting the device I'm able to successfully send and receive MIDI messages from an externally plugged in MIDI controller like the [OP-Z](https://teenage.engineering/products/op-z) or [Ableton Push](https://www.ableton.com/en/push/). I use the "MIDI Network Setup" Window in order to relay the messages from the device to the iOS application. The setup looks like this:

[image: Three windows on MacOS Desktop: MIDI Studio, MIDI Network Setup, and iOS Simulator]

However, when I plug the device directly into an iPhone or iPad nothing happens. Is there a specific set of features in AudioKit (I'm using v5) or CoreMIDI that I should be enabling in order to make this occur? Or is there something that's inherent to MacOS that isn't available on iOS, like a special entitlement?

The code is based off [this AudioKit cookbook example](https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/main/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/MIDIMonitor.swift) and I have Inter-App Audio and App Sandbox entitlements screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I'll cover this in tomorrow's office hours if you like.  Check AudioKitMan on Twitter for details.

Comment: Just followed. Looking forward to the next office hours! Thanks

Comment: See if after you connect your MIDI device you restart the app and it might just work. By connecting a new midi device, AudioKit is not going to automatically connect to it (although AK might have done that in the past, I think its better not to make assumptions). Quick fix is just to add a button to open all inputs, better fix will be an interface to choose which inputs to listen to.